# Need help in MS Excel for extraction

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula, excel-2013

Need help to extract alphanumeric string from a cell IN EXCEL 2013/2016
Example cells:

```
Tom Jomes 10102230SP01001 Payment
Jonas Haul 550R202202230016 Car
Holland motors 10102230C002001
Jeevan 0073669900002 cc
```

Need below result in new cell against the above:

```
10102230SP01001
550R202202230016
10102230C002001
0073669900002
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions that just state what you need are off-topic on SO. Please refer to [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Include the formula/VBA-code you tried and let us know what didn't work for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your current sample you may utilize `FILTERXML()` function.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'1234567890','')!=.]")
```

Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747) from JvdV

[image]

Comment: Allow me to make one small addition `=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>'")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'0123456789','')!=.]"),"'","")`

Comment: Nice trick to make nodes as text instead of numbers. So, it will not loose starting zeros.

Comment: Thank you @JvdV for you help in this matter. Great learning for me.

Comment: Thank you @Harun24HR for you help in this matter. Yeah those starting zeroes were require.

Comment: @hardcrusher2 So, did it work for you? If it helps then mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it).